# How to convert object and all of it's properties to array?

Tags: php, arrays, object, type-conversion

For example, if I have an object with a property which is an array of two objects and I try to do this:

```
return (array) $object;
```

The $object becomes an array with an array of two objects. 
Is there a short way to convert an object and all of its nested objects to arrays without going to each one individually?

Comment: You could try something sneaky like json_encode/decode. Why do you need this?

Comment: I'm just curious how to make everything an array if I want. Something like $array['addresses'][0]['name'], instead of $object->adresses[0]->name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your not sure, if object has another object then first try to convert object into array using for loop check element is object then repeat the procedure until element is not an object.
Check out bellow code:

```
function toArray($obj)
{
    if (is_object($obj)) 
        $obj = (array)$obj;
    if (is_array($obj)) {
        $new = array();
        foreach ($obj as $key => $val) {
            $new[$key] = toArray($val);
        }
    } else {
        $new = $obj;
    }
    return $new;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple function to do it in recursive way

```
 function objtoarr ($vars) {
     if (is_object($vars)) {
        $d = get_object_vars($vars);
     }

     return is_array($vars) ? array_map('objtoarr', $vars) : $vars;
 }
```

[Working fiddle](http://ideone.com/KxyCVw)